# c compiler error with linking

Tags: c, compiler-construction, extern

Here is the error I get from the `gcc` call:

```
gcc -o rr4 shells2.c graph1.c rng.c;

  Undefined symbols:  
   "_getdisc", referenced from:  
       _main in cckR7zjP.o  
  ld: symbol(s) not found
```

The "cckR7zjP.o" keeps changing every time I call the compiler.  The code for the method is in the file `graph1.c`; its header file is called `graph2.h`, and I am importing it to the file with the main method called `shells2.c` using:

```
#include "graph2.h"
```

The method or function definition is:

```
int getdisc(int i){ return disc[i];}
```

which attempts to return the i<sup>th</sup> member of the array disc created by

```
static int *disc;
```

that I already initialized in some other method! I think the problematic call is:

```
for (iter = 0; iter < n; iter++) {
    if (getdisc(iter) == cln)
        avgbtwn += get_betweenness(iter);
}
```

This seems like a linker problem I checked with some other questions, and I think I am linking my method properly (and am using the same method elsewhere in the code) but I still can't figure this out.

Edit: So I switched the order of the command in linux to

```
gcc -o rr4 graph1.c rng.c shells2.c
```

as per Soren's suggestion and the function compiled as normal, does anyone know why?
Further it seems when i put a trailing line break in the file graph1.c alleviates the problem.

Comment: I think You need to link some library add -lsomething flag to your compiler

Comment: Can you describe the layout of the files again a bit more clear? Also, what's in cckR7zjP.c, and where do you use it? it seems like wee miss a part here.

Comment: There is _no_ `cckR7zjP.c`, that's just a temporary name chosen for the object file.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where the `getdisc()` function is defined? Which file? Can you confirm that it's actually in one of `shells2.c`, `graph1.c`, or `rng.c`? You mentioned a `graph2` module but it doesn't appear to be linked in, based on the `gcc` command line you posted.

Comment: Here is where the confusion might be coming from graph2.h is the header for graph1.c (don't ask) `getdisc()` is defined in graph1.c shells2.c includes graph2.h

Comment: Please tell us the minimal set of shell commands and file contents that reproduces the problem.  You probably forgot to properly include the library at the link step.

Comment: Please post the output of `gcc -c -o graph1.o graph1.c ; nm graph1.o`.

Comment: (1) what version of the compiler do you use?  
(2) what happens if you change the order of the files so shells2.c is last?

Comment: There is a lot of output here is some of it (hopefully the relavent parts)   0000000000007490 b _disc
0000000000006cc5 T _get_disc
0000000000007400 S _get_disc.eh Benjamin-Kadishs-MacBook-Pro:rreg benjaminkadish$ 0000000000006cc5 T _get_disc
-bash: 0000000000006cc5: command not found
@Mike

Comment: WAIT ONE GOLDARNED SECOND!!! Is that a `get_disc` I see in that output??? What's that underscore doing in the middle of it??? :-)

Comment: @Soren I changed the order and it compiled!

Comment: sorry i changed the function from getdisc to get_disc when I was editing

Comment: Why edit the output? Do you take some perverse pleasure in making it harder for those trying to help? :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have switched it back!

Comment: Rather than changing the order I'd do something like this to separate the compile and link phases: `gcc -c shells2.c ; gcc -c graph1.c ; gcc -c rng.c ; gcc -o rr4 shells2.o graph1.o rng.o`. It's easier to see what's happening every step of the way, and you can run tools like `nm` on the intermediate output to see what's going on. (this is more like what `make` would typically do for you, since if you change only one .c file you can rebuild one at a time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a issue in the old GCC 2.x compilers/linkers where the linker couldn't resolve linking when the symbols were not group together -- think of it as that the linker would only looks for symbols that is still needed, and it would drop symbols which were unused.

To most people the problem would manifest itself as a problem of the ordering of libraries (specified with -l or as .a).

I see from the comments that you use a mac, so it *might* just be that the mac version of the compiler/linker still has that problem -- anyway since reordering the source files solved the problem, then you certainly have some variation of this bug.

So possible solutions;

1. Group all your source files into larger files -- bad solution -- but the linker is less likely to fail with this symptom -- or
2. Try to compiler all the files to .o first and then link the .o files (using a makefile would usually do this, but may or may not resolve the problem) and possibly combine the .o into a single .a (man ar), or
3. Change the order of the source files to have the shells2.c last (which worked for you), or
4. See if upgrading your compiler helps

Sorry for the long laundry list, but this is clearly just a compiler bug which just need a simple work around.

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely an error with `getdisc` not being visible to the linker but, if what you say is correct, that shouldn't happen.

The `gcc` command line you have includes `graph1.c` which you assure use contains the function.

Don't worry about the object file name, that's just a temprary name created by the compiler to pass to the linker.

Can you confirm (exact cut and paste) the `gcc` command line you're using, and show us the function definition with some context around it?

In addition, make sure that `graph1.c` is being compiled as expected by inserting immediately before the `getdisc` function, the following line:

```
xyzzy plugh twisty;
```

If your function is being seen by the compiler, that should cause an error *first.* It may be something like `ifdef` statements causing your code not to be compiled.

By way of testing, the following transcript shows that what you are *trying* to do works just fine:

```
pax> cat shells2.c
    #include "graph2.h"
    int main (void) {
        int x = getdisc ();
        return x;
    }


pax> cat graph2.h
int getdisc (void);

pax> cat graph1.c
    int getdisc (void) {
        return 42;
    }


pax> gcc -o rr4 shells2.c graph1.c 

pax> ./rr4

pax> echo $?
42
```

We have to therefore assume that what you're *actually* doing is something different, and that's unusually tactful for me :-)

What you're experiencing is what would happen with something like:

```
pax> gcc -o rr4 shells2.c
/tmp/ccb4ZOpG.o: In function `main':
shells2.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `getdisc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or if `getdisc` was *not* declared correctly in `graph1.c`.

That last case could be for many reasons including, but not limited to:

- mis-spelling of `getdisc`.
- `#ifdef` type statements meaning the definition is never seen (though you seem to have discounted that in a comment).
- some wag using `#define` to change `getdisc` to something else (unlikely, but possible).

Comment: There was an error when I included that line the line I am using for gcc is `gcc -o rr4 shells2.c graph1.c rng.c`